# upload a processed image into server

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax

I am using imageFX to process an uploaded image and save it after processing into my server imageFX is a javascript library that turn an image into a processed canvas what i'm trying to do is take that canvas and uploaded it into my server using AJAX but i'm getting an error response here is my code :

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/pixastic/pixastic.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/pixastic/desaturate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#save").click(function () {

            var image = document.getElementById("filterimage").toDataURL("image/png");
            image = image.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
            alert(image);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "ImageFxExample.aspx/UploadImage",
                data: '{ "imageData" : "' + image + '" }',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert('Image saved successfully !');
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("error!!");
                }
            });
        });

    });
   </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

     function strfilter(filter) {
         var img = document.getElementById("<%=filterimage.ClientID %>");
         Pixastic.process(img, filter);
         document.getElementById("save").style.display = "block";
     }
   </script>
```

the Markup:

```
    <asp:FileUpload ID="fileUpload" runat="server"   />
    <asp:Button ID="upload_btn" runat="server" onclick="upload_btn_Click" Text="upload" />
    <asp:Image ID="filterimage" runat="server" ImageUrl="" />
```

server side :

```
protected void upload_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    string folderPath = "UploadedImage/";
    string imageName = fileUpload.FileName;
    string saveLocation = Server.MapPath(folderPath) + imageName;
    fileUpload.SaveAs(saveLocation);
    filterimage.ImageUrl = folderPath + imageName;
}

[WebMethod()]
public static void UploadImage(string imageData){
    string Path = "UploadedImage/";
    string folderPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(Path);
    string fileNameWitPath = folderPath + DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace("/", "-").Replace(" ", "- ").Replace(":", "") + ".png";

    FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileNameWitPath, FileMode.Create);
    BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);

    byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(imageData);

    bw.Write(data);
    bw.Close();
}
```

if i put a simple imageUrl for filterimage without using the upload it work fine but if i use the upload control it wont work and i get error message any help please

Comment: A general suggestion Jquery 1.4.1 is too old..try updating

Comment: i guess i found the solution and it's i'm uploading an images that not contain png extension

Comment: please use some punctuation, as like this your question is really hard to read. When you found an answer that works for you yourself, simply post it as answer and accept it - that way it's easier for other people with the same problem to get help

Answer (score 0):

i found the right answer and it's converting the image to 'png' b4 you upload it

```
protected void upload_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string folderPath = "UploadedImage/";
    string  imageName = fileUpload.FileName;

    string saveLocation = Server.MapPath(folderPath);
    string ext = Path.GetExtension(imageName);
   string name= imageName.Replace(ext, ".png");
   saveLocation = Server.MapPath(folderPath) + name;
    fileUpload.SaveAs(saveLocation);
    filterimage.ImageUrl = folderPath + name;
}
```